# Lazy Load won't work

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading

I wanted to test the Lazy Load Plugin on my Website and it won't work. I've tested everything but I couldn't find the reason for the fail. Please help me here is the HTML Code :

```
    <head>
    <link href="css/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="Script/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Script/jquery.lazyload.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Script/bilderLaden.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    ...
    <img class="lazy" src="image/grey.gif" data-original="imag/example.jpg"            width="640" heigh="480">
```

Here is bilderLaden.js:

```
    $("img.lazy").lazyload();
```

Answer (score 1):

is the $("img.lazy").lazyload(); wrapped in a document ready function?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
});
```

or

```
(function() {

})();
```

?

And is bilderLaden.js loaded in the header?